# Large text not being saved in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a site for managing fiction writing, but the story text isn't being saved. Here's part of my _form.html.erb file for the story scaffold:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :genre %>
    <%= f.text_field :genre %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :word_count %>
    <%= f.number_field :word_count %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :story_text %>
    <%= f.text_area :story_text, :cols => "100", :rows => "10" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

And here is the show page for the story:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<h2><%= @story.title %></h2><br>
<h4>by <%= @story.author %></h4>

<br>
<hr>
<br>

<%= @story.story_text %>



<%= link_to 'Back', stories_path %>
```

The title and author are visible but the story_text isn't. I tried manually inserting via SQL commands, but it stops at line breaks, so I think that has something to do with my problem. I could remove all line breaks, replace them with "\n", and then use gsub to replace \n with the HTML break tag but I would rather fix the form to be able to do that without having to use SQL. I should mention that the data type for story_text is simply "text".

Comment: Look at your console log and see what parameters are actually being submitted. Post the log so we can see, too.

Comment: I looked. "nil" is being passed for story_text.

Comment: Is `story_text` permitted in your controller?